# MaxLength attribute not working fine in Android

Tags: android, xml

I am using an `EditText` in my xml where I want user to put in their phone numbers. I want to limit the number of digits (should be 10 digits) so I applied `maxLength="10"`. All cases are working fine except if I start my number with "0", it lets me write 9 digits. 
Below is my attached code for `EditText`.

```
<EditText
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:id="@+id/phone"
                    android:textColor="#7c6596"
                    android:textColorHint="#cab2e5"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_radius"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Phone number"/>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact input you are trying?

Comment: `maxLength` specifies the maximum number of characters entered - it seems your issue is how you are processing the text field and accepting such text with leading 0's (btw a 0 is a digit).  It may be best if you post what input is acceptable and not acceptable to help define your problem.  Note also there is a `phone` input type which simply presents a slightly different keypad that resembles phone input.

Comment: O is also a number!

Comment: @Andy for example. if I put all 0's in my edit field, it lets me write 9 digits like this (000000000) but it should allow me to write 10 digits (0000000000). Another example is: "0123456789" this is okay but if I write this: "066566655" then I can't write more(Note there are 9 digits in this case).

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution. 
I was applying `maxLength` in xml and in the same time I also had a `TextWatcher` on that field in my class file. I removed the `TextWatcher` and now all cases are perfectly handled.
Hope it helps someone. Cheers !!